# Prove $n!\mid\prod_{k=i}^{i+n-1}k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factorial, products

I have no idea how to prove this, I haven't yet learned much about this kind of product.

$$
n!\mid\prod_{k=i}^{i+n-1}k
$$

Comment: First try proving the product of j consecutive integers is divisible by j.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** a very interesting fact you can use :

$$\dbinom {i+n-1} {i-1}=\frac{\cdots  }{n!}$$

Comment: Could you expand on that? I got to $\frac{i+n-1}{n!}$, but what can I use that for?

Comment: if you take $p=\prod_{k=i}^{i+n-1}k$ then $$\frac{p}{n!}=\dbinom {i+n-1} {i-1}$$ and we know that binomial coefficients are integers, hence $\frac{p}{n!}$ is an integer which signifies that $n!$ divides $p$

Comment: What if $i+n-1 < 0$? then I shouldn't be able to use the binomial coefficient identity, right?

Comment: directly you can't, but you  can do it separably , by replacing every term $k$ by $-k$ and the product will become a product of consecutive positive integers

Answer (score 1):

Notice that this relates strongly to the so-called **choose** function, $C(n,k)$, which is defined as
$$C(N,k) = \frac{N!}{k!(N-k)!}$$
Since the right-hand side can be written $ \prod_{k=i}^{i+n-1} k = \frac{(i+n-1)!}{(i-1)!} $, the question is really asking you to verify that
$$C(n+i-1, n) = \frac{(i+n-1)!}{n!(i-1)!} \in \mathbb Z$$

Comment: I realized I could write the product that way, but I don't understand what to do next, how can I approach verifying that?

Comment: Also, doesn't this only work if $i>1$?